# CSS gradients cross-browser

Tags: css, gradient

I have this CSS generated from this URL:
http://ie.microsoft.com/testdrive/graphics/cssgradientbackgroundmaker/default.html

```
/* IE10 Consumer Preview */ 
background-image: -ms-radial-gradient(center bottom, circle closest-corner, #FFFFFF 0%, #BCD2E3 100%);

/* Mozilla Firefox */ 
background-image: -moz-radial-gradient(center bottom, circle closest-corner, #FFFFFF 0%, #BCD2E3 100%);

/* Opera */ 
background-image: -o-radial-gradient(center bottom, circle closest-corner, #FFFFFF 0%, #BCD2E3 100%);

/* Webkit (Safari/Chrome 10) */ 
background-image: -webkit-gradient(radial, center bottom, 0, center bottom, 487, color-stop(0, #FFFFFF), color-stop(1, #BCD2E3));

/* Webkit (Chrome 11+) */ 
background-image: -webkit-radial-gradient(center bottom, circle closest-corner, #FFFFFF 0%, #BCD2E3 100%);

/* W3C Markup, IE10 Release Preview */ 
background-image: radial-gradient(circle closest-corner at center bottom, #FFFFFF 0%, #BCD2E3 100%);
```

How can I make this where it degrades well to older browsers and uses the image instead of the gradients?

Here is my current CSS with a background image, also, my image is currently 1600X144 and I'd like the center of the gradient centered accordingly.:

```
.navbar .navbar-inner {
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4), 0 0 10px rgba(239, 24, 3, 0.1);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4), 0 0 10px rgba(239, 24, 3, 0.1);
    box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4), 0 0 10px rgba(239, 24, 3, 0.1);
    background: url(../images/bgHeader2.png);
}
```

Comment: This *should* use the background image if none of those `radial-gradient` codes is supported in the browser. Can you show an example where this is not working?

Comment: Have you tested it? As it is, it should work just fine.

Comment: I recommend you use http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/ great css gradient generator

Comment: @paradise looked at that one and it wouldn't make one anything like my image.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The generated code already degrades for older browsers: they'll use the `background-image: url(bgHeader2.png);` property value and disregard the gradient properties because they can't parse them (this is why the ordering of the properties is important).

I can't see anything wrong besides the fact the generated code is very verbose.

Comment: Yup, #FFFFFF can be very well written as #fff. Also, 0% and 100% aren't needed.

Answer (score 1):

Others have mentioned that your example should work and degrade gracefully, so I won't go in to that.

As for your side note about centering the gradient-image. The easiest way to control the position of a background image is throught the [`background-position`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/background-position) property.

Not sure how you wan't to position your background, but a wild guess is this:

```
background-position: center center;
```

You could also do it straight in the background-property:

```
background: url(../images/bgHeader2.png) center center;
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that it wouldn't be better to only use `background: ....` instead of `background-image:` (I do not know if this might help, but if you check [ColorZilla](http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/), it shows an example with old browser support. But the gradient should work in IE6...

Comment: using the shorthand `background:` property causes any previously-defined long-hand properties to be overwritten, even if they weren't specified in the shorthand property. That's why CSS generators don't usually use the shorthand syntax.